# A problem with a website's security certificate for Apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, domain, certificate

How can I fix a problem with my certificate for SharePoint Apps?

I receive an error "Mismatched Address" for every app that I deploy.

The url looks like `https://apps-c27f8411d0134e.appsdomain.com/sites/dev/SharePointApp/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=...`

[image]

Please, help me, I have no ideas how to fix this problem.

Comment: I also get the mismatched cert error, but only when we access the site from outside of your network.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different certificate, wildcard certificate i.e *.contoso.com will only apply for 1st level, that means domain1.contoso.com or domain2.contoso.com but if you use in this case apps.domain1.contoso.com will bring you that error.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/06/13/working-with-wild-card-certificates.aspx

Hope that helps you

Comment: Yes! The problem was solved. I have created certificate for my PC `<myPCName>.loc` and updated mappings of IP addresses using `OSHE: Hosts Editor`.
_127.0.0.1 `<myPCName>.loc`_